# ASP.NET Page says I need to reference an assembly that does not exist!

Tags: asp.net, compilation

My asp.net site has to run on several client servers.  It's working fine on a majority of them, but a couple have run into an error message on a few pages:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'MetaNameValuePair' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'App_Code.t_3vcono, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The type 'MetaNameValuePair' is actually defined in a .cs file within my App_Code folder, not an external assembly.  Is it failing to compile that .cs file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Attempt 1:

[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284433/strange-error-cs0012-the-type-x-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenc) was asked a couple of months back and look at those answers.

Attempt 2:

Have you cleared the "Temporary ASP.Net Files" for the site, usually found at C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files?  There may be an old copy lingering around.

Comment: I looked at that, but it was a question about referencing a "real" assembly (.dll).  As I mentioned in my question, the type listed is not defined in a separate assembly, it's defined within the same site.

Comment: Clearing the temporary files looks like it did it.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

For some special cases you could get rid of this if you disable [batch compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the Web.config file like this:

```
<system.web>
    ...
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" batch="false" />
    ...
</system.web>
```

After compiling, you can change the value back to True or remove the "batch" attribute, and then rebuild successfully.

Comment: I found that clearing the cache didn't work me - and while this slows things down it did work as a second resort.

Answer (score 1):

Had this numerous times.  The solution is to close and open Visual Studio.

In my case at least it seemed to hove something to do wit

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions worked for me. The code that it is complaining about is this:

```
thisSession = ((SiteMasterPage)this.Master).foo;
```

I'm casting the page's generic master page to the specific master page which grants me access to the foo object on the page's master page which is a complex object with trivial user data.

If you want to know why I'm doing this, it's because so far it's the best solution. Requirements dictate that I cannot extend the page class, no session variables, or cookies, and it must be user specific data.

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I have to reply in an answer. :(

Comment: You should open a new question with your specific case, with a paragraph at its end explaining why other similar questions you have seen does not cover your case.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions have worked for me in the past, but not this time.

I finally found the cause: one of those server side tags (like **<%# Eval("Something") %>** ) from the attribute of a control on the aspx page.

I'd added it shortly before the problem appeared, and removing it made the problem go away. It was in a TemplateField on a GridView.

Bizarre, but that's what did the trick.